# BigQuery distributed transactions

Tags: google-bigquery, distributed-transactions, eventual-consistency

I'm trying to architect a microservice based system utilizing BigQuery as one of services. We need to preserve eventual consistency between BigQuery and other microservices, so that changes to BigQuery (data uploads, table creates, etc) were eventually propagated to other services.

I'm wondering if BigQuery has mechanisms, supporting this kind of consistency? As I checked, BigQuery does not support publishing its events to pub/sub, which would definitely solve a problem.

I'm thinking of utilizing labels for this. I hope updates of data and labels should be atomic in respect to one API call.

Something like keeping two labels with current version and committed version, and maybe uncommitted operation type. Mutation operation increases current version and queues task, publishing update to pub/sub, which on success updates committed version to match the current one.  I though see a number of problems with this solution.

Basically, there is a broader question, of how APIs need to be designed to support eventual consistency with other systems, and if it is possible to use API not specially designed for this, in an eventually consistent distributed system.

Comment: I don't fully understand your use case, or why you'd do this TBH, but there's nothing stopping you sending your BigQuery logs to PubSub using Stackdriver's log sinks (exports): https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/

Comment: Reasons are obvious - trigger some associated state transitions, notify users about change, start batch processing pipeline... Same reasons why GCS supports triggers in cloud functions https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage

Thanks for the idea about utilizing logging, just would be good to know if logs are sent in an eventually consistent way and cannot be lost, when for example BigQuery state is updated and Stackdriver system is not temporarily available for some reason, are there retransmission attempts?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that